# Cryptmount / setup is missing from initramfs

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, lvm, initramfs

So silly me decided to do a "apt autoremove" which decided to remove cryptmount which if I was more vigilant would have realised from the error messages that came up during the uninstall that I should leave it alone... But seeing that it was "no longer required" according to apt, I thought it was a new version that was installed during the previous apt dist-upgrade I had just performed.

Anyways, after rebooting again... I get errors similar to...

```
warning failed to connect to lvmetad. falling back to device scanning. alert /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist 


After showing the boot screen for about 30 seconds, a busybox shell pops up:

BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.1-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

Typing exit will display more information about the failure before bringing us back to the same busybox shell:

Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.1-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)    Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)

which now complains that the /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root root partition (which uses LUKS and LVM) cannot be found.
```

Anyways, from Grub I was able to go Advanced .. then load into a previous kernel version? ... and it still has the cryptmount files there and I'm able to boot into my system fine.

If i apt update | upgrade | dist-upgrade it says my system is fully up to date.. even though I loaded an older kernel.

Now after spending the past few hours Googling and trying to rectify the issue with no luck... suddenly the advanced thing in Grub came to me to load the earlier kernel.... (i had to do this couple of days ago to go into the recovery mode to reset my password as I hadnt used this laptop for a lil while).

Anyways, I did come across something that said to do `update-initramfs -u`  which ran through a big script thing ... it appeared to have done something.  After rebooting it still couldnt load the LVM file coz it couldnt find .. like it was still missing those files.

Does anyone have any solutions on how to fix the above?

I apologise if the above is confusing.

I can access my files and content by loading via an earlier kernel on boot so i'm not too fussed, and hey it might just fix itself next time another distro is released ...

Maybe if someone even has a suggestion on updating grub2 to load the earlier kernel instead of the newer one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try reinstalling cryptmount?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cryptsetup` then `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: @N0rbert ... why. did you code edit me ?

Comment: @AlexP & Joshua ... if i load via the old header ... then cryptsetup is already installed ....  if i go via the new header ... then its not installed ... and i cant install via apt because its only an ash shell ... :/

Comment: You can try and check all the crypt config following the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1084978/500982