# Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 4.15.0-34-generic boots to BusyBox

Tags: boot, kernel, 18.04, encryption, luks

The machine was a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 and used LVM and LUKS during install.
The machine was working fine on kernel 4.15.0-33-generic.

The kernel upgraded from 4.15.0-33 to 4.15.0-34-generic.
After the kernel updated, it no longer prompts for LUKS passphrase and boots straight to BusyBox v1.27.2

When booting from the older kernel, it prompts for LUKS like normal and the machine is able to boot properly.
The issue is when booting from the newer kernel.

I tried to run fsck from a liveCD of 18.04.
I unlocked the drive first then ran

```
fsck -f /deb/sda3
```

However I only get

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
```

and nothing else.

Is there a fix that I can run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `/sbin/cryptsetup` is not in initramfs file `/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic`.

You need to add `CRYPTSETUP=y` in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`.
You also need to add the `initramfs` option in `/etc/crypttab`.
Then, you have to run `update-initramfs`, which solves this problem.

Detailed solution:

1. In an other Ubuntu machine, use "Startup Disk Creator" to create a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 USB drive
2. Plug in this USB drive in a USB port of the computer that boots to BusyBox
3. When the live USB Ubuntu is ready, connect to Internet (WiFi or wired)
4. Open a terminal

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
   ```
5. Find the encrypted block device.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# blkid|grep LUKS
   /dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="4b206e76-1531-48ae-95be-ae0ed7a244c1" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="21db499d-b87b-41c6-864f-04d1531cb083"
   ```
6. Decrypt the device

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# cryptsetup open UUID="4b206e76-1531-48ae-95be-ae0ed7a244c1" nvme0n1p3_crypt
   Enter passphrase for /dev/disk/by-uuid/4b206e76-1531-48ae-95be-ae0ed7a244c1:
   ```
7. List mapped devices. `control` is a file used to send command to the device mapper. `nvme0n1p3_crypt` is the decrypted device. `ubuntu--vg-root` is a LVM logical volume in the LVM `ubuntu-vg` volume group.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# ls /dev/mapper/*
   /dev/mapper/control  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt
   ```
8. Create mount point. This is where we will mount the / of our system that won't boot.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# mkdir -p /mnt/ubuntu-root
   ```
9. Mount root logical volume

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/ubuntu-root/
   ```
10. Mount pseudo file systems

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/ubuntu-root/sys
    root@ubuntu:~# mount -o bind /proc /mnt/ubuntu-root/proc
    root@ubuntu:~# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/ubuntu-root/dev
    ```
11. Copy DNS information

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/ubuntu-root/etc/
    ```
12. Change root

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# chroot /mnt/ubuntu-root/
    ```
13. Mount `/boot`, which contains the initramfs file. This partition is unencrypted.

    ```
    root@ubuntu:/# mount /boot/
    ```
14. Install binwalk (to see the content of the init ram file system)

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# apt update
    root@ubuntu:~# apt install binwalk
    ```
15. Find offset of gzipped initramfs content

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# binwalk /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic | grep gzip
    1605632       0x188000        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 2018-10-18 13:00:32
    ```
16. The problem is that the initramfs file system does not contain cryptsetup.
    So, that is why there is no LUKS password prompt.

    ```
    root@ubuntu:/# cd /root/
    root@ubuntu:~# mkdir initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic
    root@ubuntu:~# cd initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic
    root@ubuntu:~/initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic bs=1605632 skip=1 | gunzip | cpio -i
    root@ubuntu:~/initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic# ls sbin/cryptsetup
    ls: cannot access 'sbin/cryptsetup': No such file or directory
    ```
17. To decrypt root at boot, the initramfs needs to contain:

    ```
    sbin/cryptsetup
    lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-crypt.ko
    ```
18. Add the `initramfs` option in `/etc/crypttab`

    ```
    root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/crypttab 
    nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=4b206e76-1531-48ae-95be-ae0ed7a244c1 none luks,discard,initramfs
    ```
19. Add `CRYPTSETUP=y` in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`
20. Run `update-initramfs`:

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# update-initramfs -k 4.15.0-36-generic -c -v &> update-initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic.cryptsetup.log
    ```
21. Now, we have `cryptsetup` in initramfs and the Linux kernel module `dm-crypt.ko` too:

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# grep /sbin/cryptsetup update-initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic.cryptsetup.log
    Adding binary /sbin/cryptsetup

    root@ubuntu:~# grep dm-crypt.ko update-initramfs-4.15.0-36-generic.cryptsetup.log
    Adding module /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-crypt.ko
    ```
22. Now, run update-initramfs, without -c (new) and without -v (verbose):

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# update-initramfs -k 4.15.0-36-generic -u
    ```
23. Verify that the initramfs is actually correct

    ```
    root@ubuntu:~# binwalk /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic | grep gzip
    1605632       0x188000        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 2018-10-18 14:26:29

    root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic bs=1605632 skip=1 2> /dev/null | gunzip | cpio -t 2> /dev/null |grep sbin/crypt 
    sbin/cryptsetup

    root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic bs=1605632 skip=1 2> /dev/null | gunzip | cpio -t 2> /dev/null |grep dm-crypt.ko
    lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-crypt.ko
    ```
24. Now, reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. :) Fixed my 2 encrypted disk setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nvidia hardware and are having issues with [sebhtml's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084978/527764), try a newer Linux kernel with the same steps mentioned there in the BusyBox terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To install missing cryptsetup on initramfs on Ubuntu 22 you can add the `cryptsetup-initramfs` package:

```
sudo apt install cryptsetup-initramfs
```